# How to use tic/toc inside parfor loop?

Tags: parallel-processing, matlab

My code is currently running using the `parfor` mechanism. However, if I want to count the running time of each iteration by using `tic/toc`, MATLAB responds with an `undefined function error`. Is there any solution to this problem? Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`tic` and `toc` do not exist in the `parfor` paradigm  because `tic` and `toc` are timing on a single thread.  Because you are running things in parallel, there will be thread / context switching and so the timing for each thread that is spawned when `parfor` is activated will be grossly inaccurate... which is why these commands are naturally unsupported.  You can, however, place `tic` and `toc` commands **outside** of the `parfor` loop, and you'll be able to time how long the entire `parfor` body executes, but I assume this is not what you're looking for.

Instead, you need to do a bit more work.  Instead of describing the work that you need to do, this has already been done by someone else.  You should take a look at this tool on the MathWorks File Exchange that allows for timing within a `parfor` loop here:  http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/27472-partictoc/content/Par.m

Examples on how to use this tool can be found here: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/27472-partictoc/content/html/Example_Script.html

Good luck!